# Ruby Class Definition with Optional Parameters Possible?

Tags: ruby, class, parameters

I'm looking to see if there's a way of having optional arguments in a class definition, destined for the `initialize` method.

```
class MyClass
    def initialize(parameters)
        # blah blah do something
    end
end

a = MyClass.new('alpha')    # works fine
b = MyClass.new             # throws ArgumentError
```

And the error:

```
'initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

I'm looking for a way to have optional parameters.  Sometimes I want to create an object with no parameters, but don't want to trip an error.  Sometimes I want to provide parameters and have them be used properly in the `initialize` method.

Can this be done, or are these my two options?

Comment: Your question is unclear. `initialize` is a method like any other method. What's stopping you from defining it with an optional parameter? And what does it mean for a class definition to have parameters?

Comment: No it is not.  The initialize method is called upon creation.  Fully different. Therefore, the instantiation is the one taking the parameters.   But the optional parameters did the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `Class#new` calls `initialize`, but that a method calls another method is completely normal and nothing special at all. `initialize` is just a method like any other method, and it can have optional parameters like any other method. If you want it to have optional parameters, just define it to have optional parameters. Also, it is still not clear what you mean by a "class definition with optional parameters". Class definitions don't have parameters, neither mandatory nor optional ones.

Comment: No, you're wrong again.  You CAN put your own code into `initialize`.  `Initialize` is used for that very reason.  Therefore the `initialize` method is completely special.  It's automatically called upon `new`.  What you also don't get is when you throw parameters at a new instance, that they might be empty.  Hence optional.

Comment: I don't understand why you believe that `initialize` is somehow "special" because you can "put your own code into" it. That is true for *all* methods, and it is true for `initialize` precisely *because* `initialize` is *not* special, but rather a method just like any other method, which means that you can do everything in `initialize` which you can do in every other method, including (but not limited to) putting "your own code into" it. It is not clear what you mean by "class definition with optional parameters", since class definitions don't *have* parameters, only methods and blocks do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this just like a normal method definition. You will have to supply a default value for the argument you want to be optionally. This means that if a value for the argument isn’t supplied, the default value will be used instead.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(value = "default value")
    @value = value
  end
end
```

Also, you can use:

```
def initialize(*parameters)
```

`parameters` will be an array with the values you have passed, or an empty array if you pass no values.

Comment: It was more of providing the option of having no parameters as well, which is covered by `def initialize(args=nil)`.  That's what I was looking for.